# Flexbox-based CSS not functioning on any iOS browser

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive-design, stylus

I am using Jade, Stylus and Node JS for my website. It runs fine on desktop Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Edge. It runs fine on Android Chrome and Browser. It does not function properly on iOS Chrome or Safari, showing similar failures on both. It also does not work on Safari on desktop. It seems to work on iOS9 but not iOS8 or below.

Here is a screenshot showing the difference between mobile Chrome on Android and mobile Chrome on iOS. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMNT8.jpg

Even though I am explicitly putting the -webkit-, and nib is generating the -webkit- prefixes in the compiled CSS, why is it not working on mobile iOS browsers? Here is my full CSS on Github. https://github.com/Connorelsea/LSMSA-SGO-Website/tree/master/public/css

The live website, for testing and demonstration, is here: http://www.lsmsaSGO.com

The website's full Stylus code is a few thousand lines long, but an example is as follows. My Stylus code:

```
.addMore
    text-align center

    .multButtons
        width 100%
        display -webkit-flex
        display flex
        justify-content center
        -webkit-justify-content center
        align-items center
        -webkit-align-items center
        flex-direction column
        -webkit-flex-direction column
```

The compiled CSS using Stylus and Nib.

```
  .addMore {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .addMore .multButtons {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -o-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -o-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -o-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning off `flex` on the `.issueContainer` seemed to fix things for me.

```
.issueContainer {
    /* display: -webkit-flex; */
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: row; */
    /* align-items: center; */
}
```

`.issueContainer` doesn't need flexbox to make it's children stack since that's the default behavior anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Autoprefixer CSS online](http://autoprefixer.github.io/) and you will get all current vendor prefixes for your CSS rule. Here's the result you would get:

```css
.addMore .multButtons {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this could happen for a variety of reasons. But did you know that you can view the HTML output generated by the device? If not: load the page on an iphone/ipad simulator (not an actual device). Then, open Safari on your mac (again not on the device). In the toolbar go to Preferences > Advanced and select "Show Develop menu in menu bar".

[image]

Then select Develop > Simulator and select the appropriate web page. You should, with a bit of investigation, be able to find the exact output generated for the device.

I've had problems like this a few times and normally I've only been able to debug them using the above method.

**Update 1 (iOS9):** Actually. 
[**Here's a link to the generated source code.**](http://pastebin.com/atbwjqsf) This is what the page looks like on an iPhone 5 simulator:

[image]

**Update 2 (iOS8):**

This is running os iOS8. [**Here's a link to the source**](http://pastebin.com/Vc7t3yZ9)

[image]

Comment: I don't own a Mac but I guess I could try to get my hand on a friend's and see if I can solve the issue this way.

Comment: Yeah, it's annoying that you have to use Safari to do this but partly understandable I guess. Hopefully someone will know the answer to your problem without having to do this but it is the only method I know that allows you to actually debug content from an iOS webview.

Comment: @Connorelsea I've updated my answer to include a gif of the phone displaying the page and the generated source code. (Also, I like the site too btw.)

Comment: Unfortunately what it looks like on my friend's iphones is not what it looks like in your simulator picture. So I am a bit confused. And thanks about the site. :D

Comment: Oh yours is on iOS9. Apple's support of flexbox was made far better on iOS9. I think my users with errors had some iOS8.1 or something.

Comment: @Connorelsea I've included a version for iOS8.